# How do I change the appearance of tooltips with mode: index in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, graph, chart.js, tooltip

I want to change how Chart.js renders tooltips when using `index` mode. By default, Chart.js displays a line break between tooltips for each dataset. I need to modify this behavior.

I tried using the `label` callback function but it seems Chart.js calls the function once for each dataset, not after consolidating the tooltips.

Current tooltip display:

[image: default tooltip]

Desired tooltip display:

[image: desired tooltip]

The reason I want to do this is that my graph can contain a large number of datasets and the tooltip box height exceeds the graph height and gets truncated when that happens.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone comes across this in the future, I eventually managed to get the behavior I need using the following steps:

1. Copy over the implementation of tooltips display from the ChartJS source.
2. Modify the HTML injected in this code to recreate the behavior you require.
3. Overwrite the ChartJS source for this function with your modified function.